# What does being schema-less mean for a NoSQL Database?

Tags: nosql, schema

Schemaless is a term that is currently floating around in the NoSql world.

1. What does this mean ?
2. I have a document with 3 properties today and I move to production with it, then what happens to my data when I need to add 2 more  properties to my document?
3. Is this purely a migrations problem where I need to manage my data migration or can a NoSql database create as much friction as a RDBMS or make it easier in someway ?

Comment: "schemaless" is a marketing slang for saying that there is no specific helper to altering the schema. There is no 'ALTER' function per se.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Schema-less is a bit of a misnomer, it's better to think of it as:

- SQL   = Schema enforced by a RDBMS on Write
- NoSQL = Partial Schema enforced by the DBMS on Write, PLUS schema fully enforced by the Application on Read (Externalised
  schema)

So while a supposed Schema-less NoSQL data-store will in theory allow you to store any data you like (typically key value pairs, in a document) without prior knowledge of the keys, or data types, it will be pointless unless you have some mechanism to retrieve and use the data. So essentially the schema is partially moved from the RDBMS into the application code. I say partially as you'll have added Indexes to document collections and or partitioned the data for performance, so the NoSQL DBMS will have a partial schema defined locally, and possibly enforced via Unique constraints.

As to adding additional attributes to a document/object in the store. Depending on how much padding is around the document (un-used space), in its physical data block, adding a few more key value pairs to the documents may result in the document having to be physically moved to a larger contiguous block of storage, and the associated indexes re-built. If you plan to use the new keys in a frequently utilised query then you'll be wanting to also add a suitable new index, which will obviously require some physical storage, take a while to initially build and possibly lead you to ask the sysadmin to allocate more memory to the DBMS, to allow the new index(s) to be cached.

Comment: Good point about space allocation. But specifically for point 2 & 3 , how do I manage the data w.r.t to data migration ? Is a NoSQl product smart enough to detect changes which are incremental and non-breaking v/s breaking ?

Comment: Depends on the product, but generally if you want to add additional attributes/keys to a document all you need to do is change your application code to store / utilise the new key value pairs. The DBMS dosen't care about what's stored in a document if it isn't to be indexed, and assuming there's enough space allocated for each document, such that the DBMS dosen't have to restructure it's back end.

Comment: So we need to account for possible increase in document size before hand ?

Comment: If you know it's going to grow then it may be worth increasing the padding, but this obviously depends on the size of the collection, rate of growth, how critical response times are,...... As most NoSQL DBMS systems will happily move data and re-index on update, but that does have an overhead, so if you allow a bit of free space in each document there will be less moving / re-indexing. Then again if the database is small the DBMS will have shuffled everything before anyone starts to moan about laggy updates.

Comment: @arober11 thanks for such an awesome answer. I have really understood the confusion that's around mongodb being schemaless

Comment: @arober11 assuming I use a NoSQL db like mongo, and say I use it to store documents having a dynamic structure. Now how does the java written in my application parse the document. Some how it would have to create dynamic objects on the fly as an when it sees documents with different structures( i.e sometimes an extra key value pair, sometimes a different data type altogether). How does one deal with this problem. I am actually facing such a problem, and I am looking for some work around and if not possible in java then any other technology that can do the magic ??

Comment: Have a look at the [MongoDB Java center](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/), as it lists a number of POJO <> BSON/MongoDB mappers, e.g. [morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia). Alternatively you could take a leaf out the mongoDB trainers book (they offer a free online course, with sample code) and simply cast the retrieved BSON object to a hash and have your own conditional key testing and branching logic. Per my post above in the noSQL world schema enforcement is largely in the application code.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late in the day but while searching on the topic again I found this article

http://tech.pro/tutorial/1189/basics-of-ravendb-nosql

Refer to section 3 in the article, I will quote it again for ease.

> Adding and changing data models to RavenDB couldn't be simpler. Since
>   it is a NoSQL database, it can handle additions and deletions to your
>   models very simply. If a property is added to your class, it will be
>   set to the default value of that type. If a property is deleted, then
>   upon deserialization that value will be ignored. No more futzing with
>   SQL Scripts.

This seems to be the logical answer for RavenDB.