# Are there Label properties - Is there a Neo4j schema for Labels?

Tags: neo4j, schema, cypher

How to ensure that all nodes of a label have some common properties ?

For example, I want to create a property "**name**" for all nodes of a label "Person", but I can make a mistake in writing of property name (*namee* ! for example)

Comment: This should be handled on the application level IMHO. Neo4j is schema free. Maybe you can achieve that by writing an unmanaged extension by hooking on the transaction. maybe this example can help you https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no such mechanism built in Neo4j today** (the *current version of Neo4j* at the time of writing is 2.1.6). What you are describing is some sort of schema (if you compare e.g. DDL for a RDBMS) and Neo4j is basically schema free. This type of structural integrity is [quite often handled in the application layer for NoSQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589184/what-does-being-schema-less-mean-for-a-nosql-database).

The only schema operations that are available today for Neo4j are described [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html).

Currently they include:

- Unique - e.g. `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE`
- Indexes - create an index on a label e.g. `CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)`

A comment on this answer from [Michael Hunger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728812/michael-hunger) who is part of team behind Neo4j indicates that **more constraints will be available for Neo4j in the future**. Furthermore, Michael points to the following alternatives:

- Take a look at [Structr](https://structr.org/), a layer above Neo4j that among other things enforces a stricter schema (check the schema docs [here](http://docs.structr.org/#Schema%20Editor))
- [SylvaDB](http://sylvadb.com/), an easy-to-use layer above Neo4j that also has schema support. Seems very

In addition to this, [FrobberOfBits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2920686/frobberofbits) pointed to the tool [NeoProfiler](https://github.com/moxious/neoprofiler) that contains a number of profilers, most of which run very simple Cypher queries against your database and provide summary statistics. Some profilers will actually discover data in your graph and then spawn other profilers which will run later. For example, if a label called "Person" is discovered in the data, a label profiler will be added to the run queue to inspect the population of nodes with that label.

Comment: Shameless plug here - while there are no such mechanisms built into neo4j today, there are some other tools that help with schema definitions in neo4j.  There's this, which looks at the data in an existing graph and derives a "metagraph" from that describing how the graph is wired together, and what rules it follows.   https://github.com/moxious/neoprofiler

Comment: there are also structr.org and sylvadb who add more rigid schema information on top of Neo4j. More constraints will be added to Neo4j in the future too. You can also do it on your own using a transaction-event-handler in Java, I started and PoC a while ago.