# what is mean by schema less in No SQL?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, schemaless

I am just a beginner in `No SQL`, while learning I saw its **schemaless**. Yes, I understand if I have to insert data, the data structure is not required on `No SQL` (without creating tables or collection), but other than that what it differs from SQL in the case of **schemaless**? In `SQL` I can add new fields to `table` with `queries` and `No SQL` can also do that.

Please advise if I am miss understand the concept and help me get this answer. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does being schema-less mean for a NoSQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589184/what-does-being-schema-less-mean-for-a-nosql-database)

Comment: But in sql database, you can't insert a value for column `name` if there's no such column in the schema. You'll have to modify the schema first. And in a schemaless db you can just insert the field. That's the difference.

Comment: Thank you.let me ask one more thing,in SQL if i miss spelled any field (for delete update..etc) i will get error as invalid field, so i could avoid accidental wrong manipulation in db is that will work on No SQL

Comment: "schemaless" is a marketing slang for saying that there is no specific helper to altering the schema. There is no 'ALTER' function per se.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should go through with this question and answer on stackoverflow:

[What does being schema-less mean for a NoSQL Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589184/what-does-being-schema-less-mean-for-a-nosql-database)

OR

[The Value of Schema-Less Databases](https://blog.couchbase.com/the-value-of-schema-less-databases/)

Comment: It will help me If someone tell me why it's downvoting, Please.